# Run dbt without compiling

Tags: dbt

Is it possible to do a `dbt run` with the already compiled code without the compilation being run again?

I have a project that takes a lot to compile and the running time is quite low, and I have to run it 1000s of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [partial-parse](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/global-configs/parsing#partial-parsing) flag is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not entirely correct.
Partial parsing does not prevent compilation - it simply prevents *parsing of unchanged files*. Models are compiled anyway, and you can check this by placing a "run_query" call in any model and compiling with partial parse many times. You still get better times, but compilation is unavoidable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29955590)